# Show compare sidebar block only on product en category pages

Tags: magento2, compare

I'm looking for a way to show the compare feature only on category or product pages but not on other pages like CMS pages.

I found several ways to disable the entire compare feature but can't find out how to remove the sidebar from other pages other than category or product pages.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove `compare` on the sidebar then you have to add in the layout XML file

```
<referenceBlock name="catalog.compare.sidebar" remove="true"/>
```

The above content is pasted under the XML `<body>` tag in `catalog_category_view` and `catalog_product_view`

[image]

Comment: Thnx, the sidebar itself is ok but I would like to remove the compare block from the sidebar on other then category and product pages.

Comment: I have changed my answer. so please check.

Comment: you have to add "<referenceBlock name="catalog.compare.sidebar" remove="true"/>"  is pasted under the XML <body> tag in catalog_category_view and catalog_product_view